# json dump() into specific folder

Tags: python, json

This seems like it should be simple enough, but haven't been able to find a working example of how to approach this. Simply put I am generating a JSON file based on a list that a script generates. What I would like to do, is use some variables to run the dump() function, and produce a json file into specific folders. By default it of course dumps into the same place the .py file is located, but can't seem to find a way to run the .py file separately, and then produce the JSON file in a new folder of my choice:

```
import json
name = 'Best'
season = '2019-2020'
blah = ['steve','martin']

with open(season + '.json', 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(blah, json_file)
```

Take for example the above. What I'd want to do is the following:

- Take the variable 'name', and use that to generate a folder of the same name inside the folder the .py file is itself. This would then place the JSON file, in the folder, that I can then manipulate.
- 

Right now my issue is that I can't find a way to produce the file in a specific folder. Any suggestions, as this does seem simple enough, but nothing I've found had a method to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python's [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pathlib.html) is quite convenient to use for this task:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

data = ['steve','martin']
season = '2019-2020'
```

Paths of the new directory and json file:

```
base = Path('Best')
jsonpath = base / (season + ".json")
```

Create the directory if it does not exist and write json file:

```
base.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
jsonpath.write_text(json.dumps(data))
```

This will create the directory relative to the directory you started the script in. If you wanted a absolute path, you could use `Path('/somewhere/Best')`.
If you wanted to start the script while beeing in some other directory and still create the new directory into the script's directory, use: `Path(__file__).resolve().parent / 'Best'`.

Comment: This looks to work perfectly, nice one! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, instead of doing everything in same place have a separate function to create folder (if already not present) and dump json data as below:

```
def write_json(target_path, target_file, data):
    if not os.path.exists(target_path):
        try:
            os.makedirs(target_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise
    with open(os.path.join(target_path, target_file), 'w') as f:
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Then call your function like :

```
write_json('/usr/home/target', 'my_json.json', my_json_data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use string format

```
import json
import os
name = 'Best'
season = '2019-2020'
blah = ['steve','martin']
try: 
    os.mkdir(name) 
except OSError as error: 
    print(error)  
 
with open("{}/{}.json".format(name,season), 'w') as json_file:
    json.dump(blah, json_file)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `os.path.join()`:

```
with open(os.path.join(name, season+'.json'), 'w') as json_file
```

The advantage above writing a literal slash is that it will automatically pick the type of slash for the operating system you are on (slash on linux, backslash on windows)

Comment: Looks great, as I am running os on the same script. Problem is I am getting an error when I run this: 

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Best\\2019-2020.json'`

Added just the part you suggested to it, so might be it's not creating a folder when that hasn't already been placed ahead.

Comment: This function will not create folders. Use `os.mkdir()` to create folders